# Applying Angular Bootstrap Drop Down Example

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to bring drop downs into my project and I took the code from the example. The drop down appears as in the example but when I click it nothing happens.

```
<form class="form" name="form"  novalidate>
  <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            dropdown-toggle
            ng-disabled="disabled">
      Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
</form>
```

Now the controller for this html:

```
angular.module('startupApp').controller('DropdownCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
    $scope.items = [
        'The first choice!',
        'And another choice for you.',
        'but wait! A third!'
    ];

    $scope.status = {
        isopen: false
    };

    $scope.toggled = function(open) {
        $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
    };

    $scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.status.isopen = !$scope.status.isopen;
    };
});
```

Comment: Which Bootstrap/AngularJS integration lib are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angular Fullstack. Within the client there is a bower_components folder with an angular-bootsrap folder with a ui-bootstrap.js file which sounds like the one in the demo code.  The example is found here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Yes, what's the problem? I mean that's the right library right?

Comment: No problem. Added relevant tags accordingly.

Comment: Then why isn't the dropdown working?

Comment: No idea. I've never used Angular.

Comment: I went and downloaded the latest angular-bootstrap just to be sure but it didn't make a difference. Yes it is properly installed in my app also . . .

Comment: Typical culprit for this issue is the bootstrap.js event handlers are conflicting with the ui-bootstrap directive. Don't load the bootstrap.js and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle I just found the answer that worked for my case.  I only needed to add parse-angular to my angular.module('myapp'['parse-angular']).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I solved by deleting the line **dropdown-toggle**

I don't know what the problem is but it works well in this way

Here what I did:
This si the original example:

```
    <!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is the code without  **dropdown-toggle**

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit:

The above example works if you are using angular-ui-bootstrap **Version: 0.10.0**

Now I've changed the ui-bootstrap using this

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

And now all work like a charm

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me as well with version 0.10.0.

Comment: For me the solution was exactly the opposite: I need to make sure the button has the `dropdown-toggle` attribute, and the parent `div` the `dropdown` attribute, or else the button has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: If you're using version [0.14.3](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/0.14.3/src/dropdown), you have to use `uib-dropdown` and `uib-dropdown-toggle` as attributes.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems in your code:

Your HTML is not valid, the last `<div>` tag shouldn't be there

```
<form class="form" name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                dropdown-toggle
                ng-disabled="disabled">
            Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

You did not reference `ui.bootstrap` as a module dependency

```
angular.module('startupApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
```

Did you include the right files ?

- AngularJS
- Angular UI Bootstrap
- Bootstrap CSS

You don't need anything special in your controller, the `dropdown` and `dropdown-toggle` directives are self-sufficient.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/wh6zbna1/3/)

Comment: I fixed the html error but no change.  The Angular Fullstack that I use has ui.bootstrap as a dependency exactly as shown above, just in my app file. I'm not sure what you mean by include 'the right files'. I chose bootstrap and ui-bootstrap as dependencies when I setting up the seed using Yeoman/Bower. Because of this I have folders for angular, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap, bootstrap-sass-official . . .

Comment: Well then try to reproduce it in a JsFiddle or I won't be able to help much more.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say thank you to Jorge Casariego for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28023903/1238150). His answer helped me to get much further.

There was one problem at the end though, that neither `$scope.toggled = function(open) {...}` nor `$scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {...}` where called when someone interacted with the Dropdown ([see example of them here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27576480/1238150)). After looking into the [ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js) code I had to further adjust the html-code:

- the attribute `dropdown` should be a class-value not a attribute itself.
- `is-open=...` is not needed, ui-bootstrap will take care of it
- attach a `ng-click` to the `<a>` element in the list.

This did not work for me (**`dropdown` as an attribute**):

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
   ng-disabled="disabled">
    Choose category <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="category in interactions">
      <a ng-click="toggleDropdown($event)" data-category="{{category.name}}">
       {{category.displayName}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But this did (**add `dropdown` as a class value**):

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
   ng-disabled="disabled">
    Choose category <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="category in interactions">
      <a ng-click="toggleDropdown($event)" data-category="{{category.name}}">
       {{category.displayName}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The rest of my Angular App looks like this then:

```
$scope.toggleDropdown = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  console.log('This is your event now: ', $event);
};
```

I know there are newer versions available of [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), but for the record I put it up here. It works [with version **0.10.0**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js).