# How to open bootstrap dropdown menu on page load using ONLY AngularJS? (Absolutely NO jQuery)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

AngularJS & Bootstrap greenhorn here with a question regarding bootstrap dropdown menus. I've been trying to modify a page where the dropdown menu is automatically open upon page load (as requested by our customer). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495374/bootstrap-dropdown-open-on-pageload) exactly the same as what I want to achieve, however the accepted solution uses jQuery, and we're absolutely forbidden to use jQuery. :(

When I tested the page using Firefox & IE, I noticed that the div under the <-- Single Button --> comment becomes:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown ng-animate open" is-open="status.isopen" uib-dropdown="" data-ng-animate="2">
```

... so I tried adding the "open" class using ng-class and some conditional expressions (based from [this link](http://www.bootply.com/lfXdoOsBRc)) but it didn't work.

Is there any workaround for this that utilizes AngularJS or CSS? I've been trying to solve this for a long time now, without much success.

Thank you in advance.

---

Code snippet:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-12 c col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 headerDivision" ng-controller="ctrlDropdown">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav headerNavStyle">
        <li class="menu-item" style="margin-top:15px">
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">

            <!-- Hamburger menu -->
            <img uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="isMainMenu=true; isSubMenu=resetMenu(); getLinks(); bStopPropagation=true;" src="burger.png">

            <!-- Main menu -->
            <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" ng-click="bStopPropagation && $event.stopPropagation()">

            <!-- Main Menu -->
            <li role="menuitem" class="main-menu-item" ng-repeat="link in links" ng-click="whatMenu(link.name); isSubMenu=false;" ng-show="isMainMenu">
            <img id="{{link.icon}}">{{link.name}}<img class="navi-expand-icon">
            </li>
            <!-- End Main Menu -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and asking questions, I finally got this working by utilizing the $timeout service and taking advantage of the dropdown menu's behavior when clicked by programmatically triggering a click event.

1. HTML > added ng-init="displayMainMenu()" and id="nav-burger" in the img tag:

   ```
       <li class="menu-item" style="margin-top:15px">

           <!-- Single button -->
           <div class="btn-group open" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">

           <!-- Hamburger menu -->

           <img ng-init="displayMainMenu()"id="nav-burger" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="sMainMenu=true; isSubMenu=resetMenu(); getLinks(); bStopPropagation=true;" src="burger.png">

           <!-- Main menu -->
   ```
2. AngularJS > declared $timeout in controller and added function displayMainMenu():

   ```
   app.controller('ctrlDropdown', function ($scope, $timeout) {
       // variables and functions here

       //...

       $scope.displayMainMenu = function () {
           var domElement = document.getElementById('nav-burger');

           //alert('before timeout');

           $timeout(function () {
               angular.element(domElement).triggerHandler('click');
           }, 0);

           //alert('after timeout');

           //alert(domElement);
       }
   }
   ```

I hope my solution helps somebody else in the future.

Thanks to everyone who replied!

Answer (score 0):

you could try the example for angular js dropdown found here at [Applying Angular Bootstrap Drop Down Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576480/applying-angular-bootstrap-drop-down-example)    or http://angularjs4u.com/demos/angularjs-bootstrap-ui-drop-demo/

Answer (score 0):

you can apply page load without jquery also like this

```
function func1() {
  // your custom functions
}
window.onload=func1;
```